# Is it correct that we use both, MassIndexer and manual indexing from Hibernate Search in our application?

Tags: spring, lucene, hibernate-search

Recently, I joined a project that is using Hibernate Search.

I suspect we have a glitch in our app that causes ignoring newly indexed data by other background job due to using `FullTextEntityManager` in 2 places:

1) While performing the search of target data from UI, we use MassIndexer to index the data at first search request, and all subsequent search requests will not cause reindexing:

```
private final AtomicBoolean initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
public FullTextQuery buildTransactionSearchQuery(SearchRequestDTO request) {
    final FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager();

    final Query expression = buildTransactionSearchExpression(request.getFilter(), fullTextEntityManager);
    final FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(expression, Transaction.class);

    return query;
}
...

private FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
    final FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    if (initialized.get()) {
        return fullTextEntityManager;
    } else {
        synchronized (initialized) {
            if (!initialized.getAndSet(true)) {
                try {
                    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            return fullTextEntityManager;
        }
    }
}
```

2) In the background job:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1_000, fixedDelay = 5_000)
private void indexAuditValues() {
    Instant previousRunTime = ...; // assume data is set
    Instant currentTime = ...;

    int page = 0;
    boolean hasMore = true;

    while (hasMore) {
        hasMore = hsIndexingService.indexAuditValues(previousRunTime, currentTime, page++);
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean indexAuditValues(Instant previousRunTime, Instant currentTime, int page) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = return new PageRequest(page, batchSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, AUDIT_VALUE_SORT_COLUMN);

    Page<AuditValue> pageResults = auditValueRepository.findByAuditTransactionLastModifiedDateBetween(previousRunTime, currentTime, pageRequest);

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager();

    List<AuditValue> content = pageResults.getContent();
    content.forEach(fullTextEntityManager::index);  // here we do index the data

    return pageResults.hasNext();
}

private FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
    return Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
}
```

Recently, our users reported that the new data doesn't appear on the search page, can it be possible due to using 2 `FullTextEntityManager`s in 2 separate threads which are not synchronized? If yes, how can it be solved?

We use file Spring boot, Hibernate Search, Lucene, and store indexes in file system.
Entities are annotated with `@Indexed` and searchable fields are annotated with `@Field`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it was part of your question, but I'll make it clear anyway: `FullTextEntityManager` can be used in two separate threads, as long as you're using a different entity manager. And if you're using Spring, it's very likely that you do. So everything is fine there.

The main problem I see in your setup is that, potentially, the two methods could execute simultaneously (if the first search query is sent before or during the first scheduled indexing). But in that case, you would rather get duplicate documents in your index than missing documents (because of the way the mass indexer works). So I don't really know what's going wrong.

I would advise to stay away from lazily executing mass indexing in the query method, and more importantly to avoid waiting for a potentially long-running operation (mass indexing) in request threads: it's a major anti-pattern.

Ideally you should only mass index when you re-deploy your application (when the customer doesn't use the application), and re-use the index after a restart. That way you never have to make requests wait for mass indexing: by the time anyone accesses the application, everything has already been indexed.

But you didn't do any of that, so I will assume you have your reasons. If you really want to reindex everything on startup, and to block search requests as long as mass indexing is not over, something like below should be safer. Maybe not flawless (it depends on your model, really: I don't know whether audit values may be updated), but safer.

1) While performing the search of target data from UI, block the request until the initial indexing is over [once again, this is a bad idea, but to each his own].

```
// Assuming the background job class is named "IndexInitializer"
@Autowired
IndexInitializer indexInitializer;

...
public FullTextQuery buildTransactionSearchQuery(SearchRequestDTO request) {
    final FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager();

    final Query expression = buildTransactionSearchExpression(request.getFilter(), fullTextEntityManager);
    final FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(expression, Transaction.class);

    return query;
}
...

private FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
    indexInitializer.awaitInitialIndexing();
    return Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
}
```

2) In the background job, use the mass indexer on the first tick, and incremental indexing on each subsequent tick:

```
private final CountDownLatch initialIndexingsRemaining = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void awaitInitialIndexing() {
    initialIndexingsRemaining.await();
}

@Scheduled(initialDelay = 0, fixedDelay = 5_000)
private void indexAuditValues() {
    if (isInitialIndexingDone()) {
        doIncrementalIndexing();
    } else {
        doInitialIndexing();
    }
}

private boolean isInitialIndexingDone() {
    return initialIndexingsRemaining.await(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}

private void doInitialIndexing() {
    // Synchronization is only necessary here if the scheduled method may be called again before the previous execution is over. Not sure it's possible?
    synchronized (this) {
        if (isInitialIndexingDone()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            initialIndexingsRemaining.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

private void doIncrementalIndexing() {
    Instant previousRunTime = ...; // assume data is set
    Instant currentTime = ...;

    int page = 0;
    boolean hasMore = true;

    while (hasMore) {
        hasMore = hsIndexingService.indexAuditValues(previousRunTime, currentTime, page++);
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean indexAuditValues(Instant previousRunTime, Instant currentTime, int page) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = return new PageRequest(page, batchSize, Sort.Direction.ASC, AUDIT_VALUE_SORT_COLUMN);

    Page<AuditValue> pageResults = auditValueRepository.findByAuditTransactionLastModifiedDateBetween(previousRunTime, currentTime, pageRequest);

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = getFullTextEntityManager();

    List<AuditValue> content = pageResults.getContent();
    content.forEach(fullTextEntityManager::index);  // here we do index the data

    return pageResults.hasNext();
}

private FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
    return Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
}
```

On a side note, you could also replace your manual, periodic indexing with automatic, on-the-fly indexing: Hibernate Search will update the index automatically when entities are persisted/updated/deleted in Hibernate ORM.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! The problem was in Hibernate converter driver (date from DB was incorrectly converted by DB driver). It added +2 hours to `Instant` object, and whenever we request the data it shifted the filter by 2 hours. To avoid this issue, we decided to use `LocalDateTime` that doesn't produce this shift between DB and Hibernate.
As for background job, it was a temporal hack to synchronize indexes on 2 instances of the application and this hack will be removed soon since we're going to add Elastic Search with centralized storage.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to check this doc https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/getting-started/orm/en-US/html_single/index.html#_initial_indexing

the following solution may be relevant

```java
import com.example.demo.model.Book;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.MassIndexer;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.session.SearchSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class EntityIndexer  implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityIndexer(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Async
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);

        MassIndexer indexer = searchSession.massIndexer(Book.class).threadsToLoadObjects(7);
        try {
            indexer.startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

in the application bootstrap you should see something like this

```
2024-03-03T11:58:11.022+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [ ID loading - 0] s.m.p.m.i.PojoMassIndexingLoggingMonitor : HSEARCH000027: Mass indexing is going to index 2 entities.
Hibernate: select b1_0.id from book b1_0
Hibernate: select b1_0.id,b1_0.author,b1_0.title from book b1_0 where b1_0.id in (?,?)
2024-03-03T11:58:11.309+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [           main] s.m.p.m.i.PojoMassIndexingLoggingMonitor : HSEARCH000028: Mass indexing complete. Indexed 2 entities.
2024-03-03T11:58:11.311+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.015 seconds (process running for 4.462)
2024-03-03T11:58:17.932+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-03T11:58:17.932+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-03T11:58:17.933+01:00  INFO 78377 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```